# DriveApp.searchFiles - Use any substring of filename to search for files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am writing appscript  code to search for files in my drive.
Below are files in my google drive.

t_abcd.txt

p_abcd_0211.txt

j_abcd.docx

bwt_abcd.txt

etc

Note that **_abcd** is common in all of the above and only the prefix and suffix change. 
 I want the search to find all the above files when the user searches for "abcd" or its substring.

In the documentation for **DriveApp.searchFiles(params)** I could not find anywhere regular expressions or substrings being used to search for files.

One solution would be to get all files from the drive and write separate logic to identify the required files.

Is there any simpler way to do this? 
Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried just searching for `_abcd`

Comment: It doesn't work as I am using 
title contains "abcd"
As per the documentation
The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a name. For example, the name "HelloWorld" would match for name contains 'Hello' but not name contains 'World'.

Answer (score 2):

How about this workaround? Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that there are no methods for directly retrieving the files with the such filenames. So for example, how about the following workaround?

[Document of Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters) says

> fullText: Full text of the file including title, description, content, and indexable text.

The query which is used as the workaround is `fullText contains '_abcd'`. I think that when this is used as the search query, the process cost is lower than that of the full search. Sample script is as follows. I think that there are several workarounds for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Sample script:

```
var q = "fullText contains '_abcd'";
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var filename = file.getName();
  if (filename.indexOf("_abcd") > -1) {
    Logger.log(filename)
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters)

If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If my answer is not suitable for your situation, I apologize and would like to remove my answer because I don't want to confuse other users.

Comment: No it will not work. As I have mentioned ,The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a name. For example, the name "HelloWorld" would match for name contains 'Hello' but not name contains 'World'.

For my requirement, I have fetched all files from the drive and then applied logic.So I'm good now.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna Yes. Using only the contains operator, it cannot directly reach the goal. So I proposed a workaround for retrieving all files. But in this workaround, by using ``fullText contains``, the search cost can become lower than that of the method without it. In my environment, I could confirm that this script works. But in your environment, this script didn't work. Is my understanding correct? If my workaround cannot be used for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: When I said that the script does not work I meant that it did not meet the requirement. In the sample script that you have posted it is not retrieving all files. It's retrieving only those files from drive whose name starts with '_abcd' . That's why I did not run it as it clearly does not meet the requirement. Secondly the search cost was not an issue for me.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna Thank you for replying. About ``It's retrieving only those files from drive whose name starts with '_abcd'``, I could confirm that in my environment, the files of filename including ``_abcd`` like ``###_abcd###`` were retrieved. This is different from your environment. About this, I would like to confirm to other users. And about ``the search cost was not an issue for me.``, I couldn't notice it from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna So I proposed this workaround. But I have to apologize that I thought to reduce the cost of script.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna Because I would like to study from your question and comment, about ``It's retrieving only those files from drive whose name starts with '_abcd'``, can I ask you about the result of my script you ran? When you ran my script, the files of "t_abcd.txt", "p_abcd_0211.txt", "j_abcd.docx" and "bwt_abcd.txt" cannot be retrieved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, I tried your script and suprisingly it finds files like ##_abcd##. However when searched for 'bc' or 'bcd' the same file dosen't appear. The script should be able to find a file using any substring of the file.

Comment: You can see the below documentation of how fulltext works if not have seen already.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna About ``when searched for 'bc' or 'bcd' the same file doesn't appear.``, you want to also retrieve files which have the filenames like ``##_bc##`` and ``##_bcd##``.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Any substring of the filename. Lets say a filename is "Hat"
Then 

H,a,t,Ha,at,Hat 

Any one of the above 6 search strings should be able to find the file "Hat".

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna I apologize for my poor English skill. I could understand about what you want to do now. I had thought that you wanted to use the constant search value. But from your reply, it seems that the search value has to be created by combining each character. By the way, the prefix of ``_`` is constant? When the search value is ``Hat``, it's like ``_H, _a, _t, _Ha, _at, _Hat``.

Comment: No, I used the underscore just as an example. Its not constant.

Comment: @Abhishek Bapna In that case, ``_`` is included in ``Hat`` as one character of combination? For example, it's like ``H_at``.

Answer (score 1):

With **DriveApp.searchFiles(params)** you can use ***title contains*** "X" to get your files without using regular expressions and without having to take extra steps needed when searching with ***fullText contains***.

Building on [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356788/11551870), here's an example function that logs the names of all Drive files with names containing "_abcd":

```
function findFiles() {
  var q = "title contains '_abcd'";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    filename = file.getName();
    Logger.log(filename)
  }
}
```

References:

- [DriveApp.searchFiles
  docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String))
- [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356788/11551870)

Answer (score 0):

As of now the query behaves:

- able to search abcd if file starts with it `abcd_slide`, `abcd_sheets`, `abcd_doc`.

[image]

- able to search abcd if it is another word.

[image]

- Cannot search it is a subtext doc_abcd, sheets_abcd, slide_abcd.

Try creating a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909), to clarify its function.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot 
I have created a issue for feature request. Below link for reference
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125169808